# Separating the labels with lines in BarChart

Tags: plotting, labeling, charts

Is there a way to draw a dotted line between the labels of a `BarChart`? In the following graph, I want to draw a line between for example "Rawlsian with \n corrected income taxes" and "Utilitarian (Progressive)". Since my actual chart have some other bars, instead of making labels' font small, I want to separate them with some lines among them. (They will not be visible on slides if I make them small)

```
 BarChart[{{10, 20, 30, 10}, {30, 20, 10, 4}, {4, 15, 40, 20}} ,
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[
    Rotate[#, 
       360 Degree] & /@ {"Rawlsian with \n corrected income taxes", 
      "Utilitarian (Progressive)", 
      " Utilitarian (Progressive) with \n corrected income taxes"}, 
    Before], None}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Not exactly what you want: `Framed[Rotate[#, 360 Degree], FrameStyle -> Dotted] & /@labels`

Comment: Rotating `360 Degree` is the same as not rotating. Shorten to `Framed[#, FrameStyle -> Dotted] & /@labels`

Answer (score 2):

I would do it by inserting two empty bar charts, each labelled with a string of periods. Like so:

```
BarChart[
  {{10, 20, 30, 10}, {}, {30, 20, 10, 4}, {}, {4, 15, 40, 20}},
  ChartLabels ->
    {Placed[
      {"Rawlsian with \n corrected income taxes",
       Style["........................... ", 16],
       "Utilitarian (Progressive)",
       Style["........................... ", 16], 
       "Utilitarian (Progressive) with \n corrected income taxes"},
      Before],
    None},
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
  BarOrigin -> Left,
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: bar_chart]

#### Update — Aligning the dotted lines

```
cdots = Style[StringJoin[ConstantArray["\[CenterDot]", 27]] <> " ", 18]
BarChart[
  {{10, 20, 30, 10}, {}, {30, 20, 10, 4}, {}, {4, 15, 40, 20}},
  ChartLabels ->
    {Placed[
       {"Rawlsian with \n corrected income taxes", cdots,
        "Utilitarian (Progressive)", cdots, 
        "Utilitarian (Progressive) with \n corrected income taxes"},
       Before],
     None},
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: aligned]

Comment: the dotted lines are not aligned with the ticks properly

Comment: @M.R. Why should they be? They are not intended to relate to the ticks -- they are only intended as separators for the labels. If it really bothers you, you can replace `.` with `\[CenterDot]`

Comment: @Hossein. Those marks aren't ticks; they are data group indicators. They are intended to help the viewer associate the label with data group that it labels. I do not know how to eliminate them. I do know how to align the dots to their group indicator. Perhaps it will make the chart look better to you that way. M.R. already complained about it, so I guess the lack of alignment is really more bothersome than I thought. I have made an update showing how do the alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Given m_goldberg's clever trick that provides a simple and effective solution, the following is definitely an overkill ... but added flexibility may be useful.

A covenient way to inject stuff into charts is to use a custom `ChartElementFunction`. The function `ceF` below injects desired lines in the middle of group spacings using coordinate information (accessible to chart element functions) and `BarSpacing` information passed as metadata.

We modify the input data associating with the first element of a data group a number that represents the offset from the left-bottom coordinate of the associated rectangle. Making this metadata depend on the `BarSpacing` option value we center the line in the spacing between data groups. The arguments control the starting point, the length and the style of the line.

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[start_: 2, offset_: 120, style_: Directive[Black, Thick , Dashed]] := 
 Module[{}, {ChartElementDataFunction["Rectangle"][##], 
  style, If[#3 === {}, {}, Line[{{-start, -#3[[1]]/2 + #[[2, 1]]}, 
       Offset[{-offset, 0}, {-start, -#3[[1]]/2 + #[[2, 1]]}]}]]}] &
```

**Examples:**

```
options = {ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"Rawlsian with \n corrected income taxes", 
   "Utilitarian (Progressive)", 
    " Utilitarian (Progressive) with \n corrected income taxes"}, Before], None}, 
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left, ImageSize -> Large};
```

With default arguments for `ceF`:

```
BarChart[{{10, 20, 30, 10}, {30 -> .2, 20, 10, 4}, {4 -> .2, 15, 40, 
   20}}, options, BarSpacing -> {0, .2}, ChartElementFunction -> ceF[]]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[{{10 -> .1, 20, 30, 10}, {30 -> .6, 20, 10, 4}, {4 -> .6, 15, 40, 20}}, 
 options, BarSpacing -> {0, .6}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ceF[-2, 150, Directive[Thickness[.005], DotDashed, Red]]]
```

[image]